# subsonic 2 join on multiple columns

Tags: mysql, join, subsonic

I want to transfer the following statement to SubSonic 2.2

```
    SELECT b.*
    FROM tableA a
      INNER JOIN tableB b
        ON (a.year = b.year AND a.month = b.monath AND a.userid = b.userid);
```

My problem is that SubSonic's SqlQuery.LeftInnerJoin() command has no overload which takes more than one column.

Since any join can be rewritten only using where clauses, I did the following in my sql:

```
    SELECT b.*
    FROM tableA a, tableB b
    WHERE a.year = b.year
      AND a.month = b.month
      AND a.userid = b.userid
```

which should deliver the same result (in fact, at least for mysql, there is logically absolutely no difference between these statements).

But I also got stuck transfering this to subsonic because the "IsEqualTo(...)" member is smart enough to figure out that my parameter is a string and puts it into quotes.

```
DB.Select("TableB.*")
  .From<TableA>()
  .From<TableB>()
  .Where(TableA.YearColumn).IsEqualTo("TableB.Year")
  .And(TableA.MonthColumn).IsEqualTo("TableB.Month")
  .And(TableA.UseridColumn).IsEqualTo("TableB.UserId")
```

(I tried different ways in setting the IsEqualTo parameter)

```
IsEqualTo(TableB.YearColumn)
IsEqualTo(TableB.YearColumn.QualifiedName)
```

Either the parameter is interpreted as

```
TableA.Year = 'TableB.Year'
```

or I get a SqlQueryException.

Can somebody tell me how to do this query with subsonic (Either the first - with JOIN or the second one)? Thanks

Comment: Did you try checking the SQL statement that is being generated?  i.e.

    SubSonic.SqlQuery s = New SubSonic.Select().From(...;
    Console.WriteLine(s.ToString());

Comment: Yes,

as I mentioned SubSonic treads my parameter as a string (which will not result in a failure but is wrong in this case (SELECT * FROM tableA, tableB WHERE tableA.Year = 'TableB.Year' will never return a row)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With SubSonic 2 out of the box you can't.

This said, you have the following alternatives:

**Extend SubSonic**

If you're already familiar with SubSonic, you may consider to add multi-column joins to SubSonic itself.

**Use views, Stored procedures, table functions**

If you do not want to mess with SubSonics code, use views, stored procedures and/or table functions within sql server. SubSonic makes it easy to access data from views and stored procedures.

**Use an InlineQuery**

[InlineQuery](http://subsonicproject.com/docs/Inline_Query_Tool) allows you to execute any sql - if it is an option to have bare sql in your code.

**Ugly workaround with InlineQuery**

If you absolutely want to create your query with SubSonic, you can try this:

```
SqlQuery q = DB.Select()
  .From<TableA>()
  .CrossJoin<TableB>()
  .Where(TableA.YearColumn).IsEqualTo(0)
  .And(TableA.MonthColumn).IsEqualTo(0)
  .And(TableA.UseridColumn).IsEqualTo(0);
```

Build the SQL statement, and replace the parameter names:

```
string s = q.BuildSqlStatement();
s = s.Replace(q.Constraints[0].ParameterName, TableB.YearColumn.QualifiedName);
s = s.Replace(q.Constraints[1].ParameterName, TableB.MonthColumn.QualifiedName);
s = s.Replace(q.Constraints[2].ParameterName, TableB.UserIdColumn.QualifiedName);
```

Then use s with an InlineQuery.

Comment: I used the InlineQuery for this, maybe I will extend the subsonic source later if I have some idle time.